# schema-element() for SequenceType on xsl:variable with literal result element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to understand how `schema-element()` works when used as a `SequenceType` with literal result elements. This is my stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:import-schema>
    <xs:schema>
      <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="bar"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </xsl:import-schema>

  <xsl:variable name="test" as="schema-element(foo)">
    <foo bar="baz"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="$test"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon-EE 9.4.0.4 (in Oxygen 14.1) is giving me the following compilation error `Required item type of value of variable $test is schema-element(foo); supplied value has item type element(foo, {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}untyped)`

According to [XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=OnqLX4RgOkIC)

> When the construct «schema-element(N)» … is used in a SequenceType,
>   then N must be the name of a global element … declaration in an
>   imported schema.

elsewhere in the same source

> «as="schema-element(EVENT)"» indicates that [a parameter] must be an element node validated as being
>   either an EVENT or an element in the substitution group of EVENT.

It seems like `<foo bar="baz"/>` should validate as a `foo` element by the imported schema. `@xsl:type` seems like it would help, but only if I had a named complex type in my imported schema. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `<foo xsl:validation="strict" bar="baz"/>`?  The error message suggests the result element is created without type annotations so perhaps the validation needs to be requested explicitly, the `as` attribute might not suffice. But I am not too familiar with schema aware XSLT 2.0 so it is a suggestion for you to try.

Comment: This clears the compilation error but then gives a runtime validation error `Attribute @xsl:validation is not allowed on element <foo>`. I suppose that's somewhat better but still doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: Ah, after reading the chapter the @c-m-sperberg-mcqueen pointed out I figured out what I was doing wrong. This solution is correct, but I had saxon doing input validation and I was running the stylesheet against itself, thus triggering the error.

Answer (score 1):

One complication is that when xsl:variable has literal content, the variable is bound to a document node (the value may be coerced to some other type in various ways later, of course).  In the discussion of validating temporary trees in chapter 4 of Michael Kay's book, you'll find the salutary suggestion of wrapping the 'foo' element in an xsl:document instruction with a validation attribute.  For reasons that will become clear in a moment, I've renamed the variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="test0">
  <xsl:document validation="strict">
    <foo bar="baz"/>      
  </xsl:document>
</xsl:variable>
```

If one really wants `test` to be bound to a `foo` element, and not a document node dominating a `foo` element, then we can define `test` thus:

```
<xsl:variable name="test" 
              as="schema-element(foo)" 
              select="$test0/foo"/>
```

There may be a neater way to solve this, without the two-step definition, but this does work without error messages.

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer too as the pointer to chapter 4 was very helpful.